# Removing thin border appear - https://www.cloudbeds.com/ site on big screen?

Tags: css

When i check https://www.cloudbeds.com/ site, i found a thin border appear but don't know why its coming, any idea how to remove this ?

[image]

I try different CSS properties but no luck, not sure why this happening.

```
.cloud-2{
       // CSS ?
      border: none;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that your background colour (rgb(152, 157, 176)) is showing through?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just a rendering issue because on my computer it showed up for a second then disappeared.  And now it is not showing up at all.